# left join to get min date

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the first date of each booking in my database.

Table BOOKINGS is like:

```
id | id_client_booking | the_date
```

Table CLIENT_BOOKINGS is

```
id | etc | etc
```

on `BOOKINGS` each `id_client_booking` correponds to one `id` of `CLIENT_BOOKINGS`, and can have many dates.

**I would like** to get the first date of each client booking. This select gives me just the first date of all client bookings. What am I missing?

```
SELECT
min(the_date) AS start_date, id_client_booking
FROM `day_bookings`AS db
LEFT JOIN `client_bookings`AS cb ON db.id_client_booking = cb.id
```

Tried also:

```
SELECT
min(the_date) AS db.start_date, db.id_client_booking
                 ^^             ^^
FROM `day_bookings`AS db
LEFT JOIN `client_bookings`AS cb ON db.id_client_booking = cb.id
```

but that gave error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `GROUP BY`, try this:

```
SELECT MIN(the_date) AS start_date, id_client_booking
FROM `day_bookings`AS db
LEFT JOIN `client_bookings`AS cb 
ON db.id_client_booking = cb.id
GROUP BY id_client_booking
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**`GROUP BY`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) aggregate function to make [**`MIN()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) works

```
SELECT min(the_date) AS start_date, id_client_booking
FROM `day_bookings` AS db
LEFT JOIN `client_bookings` AS cb 
ON db.id_client_booking = cb.id
GROUP BY db.id_client_booking
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `AS` key word to define names for expressions or aliases.
You can't use it to point to a column directly. And hence is the *syntax* error.

```
SELECT
min(the_date) AS db.start_date, db.id_client_booking
                 ^^             ^^
FROM `day_bookings`AS db
LEFT JOIN `client_bookings`AS cb ON db.id_client_booking = cb.id
```

It should be:

```
SELECT
min(the_date) AS 'start_date', db.id_client_booking
FROM `day_bookings`AS db
LEFT JOIN `client_bookings`AS cb ON db.id_client_booking = cb.id
```